# How to pass Vue JS 'this.somestate' as a literal 'this.somestate'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, this

Let's say in a Vue JS app, I have some states

```
data () {
    optionA: {
        xaxis: { categories: ['DD'] }
    }
}
```

And a method that uses a state as a parameter like this:

```
modifyOption (optionName, xAxisCategory, dataLabelsEnabled) {
  optionName = {
    ...optionName,
    ...{
      xAxis: { categories: xAxisCategory },
      dataLabels: { enabled: dataLabelsEnabled }
    }
  }
}
```

notice the `optionName` parameter, it's supposed to be a state name for example when that method is summoned like

```
this.mofifyOption(this.optionA, 'DD MMM', true)
```

I want it to run as

```
modifyOption (this.optionA, 'DD MMM', true) {
  this.optionA = {
    ...this.optionA,
    ...{
      xAxis: { categories: 'DD MMM' },
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't expect the value of `this.optionA`, just the literal `this.optionA`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not. The best and easiest solution would be to return the new object:

```
modifiedOption(option, xAxisCategory, dataLabelsEnabled) {
  return {
    ...option,
    xAxis: { categories: xAxisCategory },
    dataLabels: { enabled: dataLabelsEnabled },
  };
}
```

to be called as `this.optionA = this.modifiedOption(this.optionA, 'DD MMM', true);`

An alternative could be to pass the property name (a string) as an argument and access the property using bracket syntax:

```
modifyOption(name, xAxisCategory, dataLabelsEnabled) {
  this[name] = {
    ...this[name],
    xAxis: { categories: xAxisCategory },
    dataLabels: { enabled: dataLabelsEnabled },
  };
}
```

to be called as `this.modifiedOption('optionA', 'DD MMM', true);`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I just tried your solutions, the second solution looks promising. But unfortunately I got this error
`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: i.reduce is not a function`

Comment: @loremdimsum That's not coming from the code in this question/answer.

Comment: oh right, that error is coming from a library i used. but your code works fine, thanks!